# Data Time the action of the first day PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi everybody how are you?
Well today I come with a very complicated question haha.
My idea is to follow the client. in my dataframe I have a column with data time, another with the person code (ex: 0aie23), in the next column the actions that this person made.
my idea is to take 'ONLY THE FIRST DAY OF ACTION' of each person. And based on that calculate the common movement made by people on the web.

let's see my example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om5xW.jpg)

As you can see in the image, user 000a54b2, performs actions on different days. I just want to stay with the actions of the first day (day 9), the dataframe continues and there are users who perform actions more than one day, I just want to stay the first day.

I would also like to know how I can do to track ... Example .. the highest percentage of users do the following 'ad campaign hit' then 'visited site' then 'viewed product' then 'checkout'. Or maybe most of the first day of action only performs 'viewed product' then 'checkout'. Thank you

Comment: Please note that this isn't a forum. It seems a bit alien but all the conversational stuff should be dropped from your post so it focusses on your issue (It can feel a bit clinical but we aren't offended by lack of "please" and "thanks"). You also shouldn't link to other resources if they form the main body of your question; Please make it self-contained

Comment: ok. if you are sure that  the minimum is on the  day 9.  I guess you that column as as a  being number you can check the data types of your dataframe by doing df.info) by the way you are talking about it. You can change to a string object and use the  below the str methods. Here it is below

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could do it:

```
##Finding the earliest day (from `dia` column) of activity for each user
earliest_day = df.groupby('person')['dia'].min().reset_index()

## Obtaining the user and event information for all "earliest day" events
df1 = df.merge(earliest_day, left_on = ['person', 'dia'], right_on = ['person', 'dia'], 
                            how = 'inner')[['person', 'event']]

## Counting the number of times each activity (event) occurred on a the first day of user experience.
df1['event'].value_counts()
```

Comment: tanks, @Vishnu Kunchur ... but I do not know why when I try to do the second step, it throws me an error.. KeyError: 'min' when I write right_on=['person','min']

Comment: yesssss, you are the best in the word !!!! . Now I need to find a way to track the client. For example, the highest percentage of people made 'viewed product' 'brand listing' 'ad campaign hit' 'visited site' 'and' 'checkout '. Or maybe most of them on their first day just did it. 'visited site' and then 'checkout'. but I can not think how to do it haha

Answer (score 0):

After reading my comment you can use the below:

```
df =df[df[dla]=='9']
```

This is some pandas query giving you a subset to the dataframe where the dla equals 9.